# How to use google storage from app engine python 3 Django

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

**Errors Overview:**

1. You need private key to sign credentials
2. App engine API's are not available

**Local machine works great:**

I have downloaded my service account key.json.
Before staring my Django app I set env variable:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[path to json key file for that service account]"
```

And everything works great.

**I deploy same code to app engine and I get error saying:**

```
you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token. see https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/auth.html?highlight=authentication#setting-up-a-service-account for more details
```

So I made changes to the app engine code's client credentials :

```
from google.auth import app_engine
import googleapiclient.discovery
credentials = app_engine.Credentials()
client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
```

3rd line in above code gives me error `The App Engine APIs are not available`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is not due to the authentication process, is about the signing process to get the credentials. This line:

> credentials = app_engine.Credentials()

According to the error, is expecting a private key but only found a token.

I'm inferring you are using App Engine Flex, since despite you imported the **app_engine** module (and not the **compute_engine** module which would be used on App Engine Flex) you are still getting the error:

> The App Engine APIs are not available

When using [App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_credentials_on_compute_engine_kubernetes_engine_app_engine_flexible_environment_and_cloud_functions) you need to sign the credentials this way:

```
def explicit_compute_engine(project):
    from google.auth import compute_engine
    from google.cloud import storage

    # Explicitly use Compute Engine credentials. These credentials are
    # available on Compute Engine, App Engine Flexible, and Container Engine.
    credentials = compute_engine.Credentials()

    # Create the client using the credentials and specifying a project ID.
    storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)

    # Make an authenticated API request
    buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
    print(buckets)
```

Comment: I am using ‘os.getenv(‘GAE_APPLICATION’)’ to check if I am on local env or GAE env. On GAE env I only do ‘storage.Client()’. ROOT path is specified on my local machines terminal before launching the Django app. It doesn’t go on app engine.

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly, let me know if you are actually using Standard version, and in that case, please update your question providing a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error but the solution above did not work for me. I am using the App Engine Standard.

This seems to be related to the upgrade to Python 3. The  App Identity Service mentioned here https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.auth.html is not available in Python 3 (there is no Python 3 option if you click on the link for  App Identity Service https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity.  I eventually got around the problem by providing the name of the credentials file for the account I was using to access the storage bucket:

```
import google.auth as auth
credentials, project_id = auth.load_credentials_from_file("credentials file")
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials,project=project_id)
bucket = client.get_bucket("bucket_name")
```

...